# Problem with double pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, breakpoints

can anyone tell me what is wrong with this piece of code

```
int* x=new int(5) ;
int i =0;
int** y = new int*[i];
for(int j = 0 ;j<5 ; j++)
{
     y[i++]=x;
}
delete[] y;
```

the compiler always triggers a breakpoint when I delete y
note that I don't want to delete the object "x"
thanks

Comment: What do you expect `new int*[0]` to do, exactly?

Comment: You have two loop iteration variables `i` and `j`, but you're only incrementing `i`.  In fact, you're incrementing it twice.  But really you shouldn't be using arrays: you want to use `std::vector`

Comment: I suppose the for loop goes over j, doesn't it?

Comment: what do you mean by "triggers a breakpoint?"  Also, y is set to size = 0.

Answer (score 7):

```
int i =0;
int** y = new int*[i];
```

Well, you have just allocated an array of pointers to int that big enough to fit... zero elements.  In your loop you are:

1. Writing outside the bounds of your array (remember, zero elements...)
2. Incrementing your loop counter twice for each iteration.
3. Never using your loop variable `j`.
4. Assigning the value of `x` to... every other element of `y`... that is outside the bounds of the array as previously mentioned.

I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish here.  How about a bit more background?  You are invoking undefined behavior by assigning outside the bounds of `y`, so anything can happen after that.

Comment: but y is a dynamic array of pointers so by changing the value of 'i' I am increasing the boundary of my array and I checked by the debugger that the value of x were assigned to y element.

and I fixed the loops but the program crashes when I want to delete y not I assign it

Comment: @neoProgram: *"by changing the value of 'i' I am increasing the boundary of my array"* - No, you definitely are not. Arrays cannot change in size dynamically.  They stay the same size that they were when they were allocated, `i` and `y` are not tied together in any sense. I think you need to study up a bit more on how arrays and pointers work in general. Your program could crash whenever because its behavior is undefined after you write outside the bounds of y.

Comment: I actually don't know the number of values that y should be assigned to

Comment: @neoProgram: If you "don't know" the number of elements you need in your array, you should start by determining that number. So that you "know" it. Until you determine the exact number of elements, you can't allocate your array. The array will not magically grow for you by itself. If you allocated an array of size `0` (which is exactly what you did), it will forever have size `0`.

Comment: but still wondering why the program worked normally when I didn't delete y and worked very well(and assigned the data correctly) but crashes when I delete the dynamic array

Comment: It didn't work.  When you write outside the bounds of an array your invoking [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This means that you can no longer make any reasonable assumptions about your program, i.e., you can't assume it will crash either.  You should read up a bit about how memory is structured in a language like C++.  Berkley has a good online course on the subject, I watched it myself for fun.

Comment: the problem with that that a piece of code like that I used it on a relatively medium size project(Logic gate simulator) in a class so called level(that indicates the levels of design and send it to the save and load and simulate functions) and it worked great with no output errors no crashes nothing except when I tried to delete a variable like this in the destructor!!!

Comment: but I think I should revise my Info about memory management in c++ as you said ,thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you initialized 'y' it has zero length since i is 0.

Comment: Sorry I edited my code I forget to edit the counter j before posting

Answer (score 2):

That line

```
int* x=new int(5) ;
```

you probably meant to be

```
int* x=new int[5]; // square brackets
```

Then in

```
int i = 0;
int** y = new int*[i];
```

you allocate for 0 elements. And in the lop you probably mean to iterate over `j`, but do incrementation on `i` twice per loop iteration:

```
for(int j = 0 ;i<5 ; i++)
{
     y[i++]=x;
}
```

Also in that loop you set each element to point to the same 5 element array. I'm pretty sure you're actually want something along this:

```
int const M = 5;
int const N = 5;

int** y = new int*[M];
for(int j = 0; j<M ; j++)
{
     y[j] = new int[N];
}
```

Comment: this is just a simple part of my code. but in my program I don't know the value of the y array so I used dynamic allocation so I can increase its size dynamically what is the problem with that?

Comment: @neoProgram: The problem with that is that the language disagrees with your assumption.  I'm not sure where you got that idea, but it is completely wrong.

Comment: @neoProgram: Do you actually think that by incrementing `i` after allocating `y` its size would change. This is not how it works. `i` get's evaluated when `y` is allocated and then never looked at again, regarding access of `y`. What you actually need is some dynamic container like std::vector then.

Answer (score 1):

y is zero-length because when you initialize it i==0
so the breakpoint is when you access y[1] in the second loop.
but this why increment twice i?

Answer (score -1):

Try out this:

```
int len = 5;
int* x=new int[len] ;
int** y = new int*[len];
int i =0;
for(int j = 0 ;j<len ; j++)
{
     y[i++]=x;
}
delete[] y;
```

you shouldn't use constants in your code, except when declaring alias-variables for it.

Comment: That's the format I used I edited my program but still wouldn't work

Comment: This example, while fixing an error or two, still makes absolutely no sense.  You declare `x` as a 5 element array, yet assign the address of the first element to every element in `y`.  You may as well use `j` for indexing into `y`, `i` is pointless.  The OP needs to tell us what he is trying to do with this code.